# Upgrade to FirebaseCrashlytics and 'No such module FirebaseCrashlytics'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I am trying to upgrade to `FirebaseCrashlytics` from `Crashlytics`. I am able to import Firebase but not FirebaseCrashlytics. Here is my podfile:

```
platform :ios, :deployment_target => "9.0"

def shared_pods
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'IGHTMLQuery'
pod 'OpenTok', '~>  2.16.3'

end

target 'MyApp' do
  #use_frameworks!

  shared_pods
end
```

I cannot uncomment use_frameworks! since it breaks other pods I am already using.

My bridging header:

```
#import "FirebaseCrashlytics/FirebaseCrashlytics.h"
#import "FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h"
```

This is what I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Do you have the same problem on device and simulator? I have the same error but only when building for simulator.

Comment: Please see my answer to this question here: ["No Such Module FirebaseMessaging" after removing 'use_frameworks!' in Podfile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74627258/6397036)

Comment: @RenatMusin try adding Firebase as a dependency

Answer (score 3):

According to the firebase docs then you just have to import Firebase, not FirebaseCrashlytics.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk#the_library_is_now_called_firebasecrashlytics they clearly mentioned importing FirebaseCrashlytics

Comment: their sample project also imports FirebaseCrashlytics. It works but dunno why it can't be found in my project ???

Comment: importing `Firebase` only helped me. But I also confirm that I switched to lower version of Firebase... if you on the latest, it should be 'FirebaseCrashlytics' and it used to work that way for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using it as a Swift framework then make sure you add it to your target's `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`

Answer (score 0):

Try running the commands below (Warning, save your documents before):

```
pod cache clean --all
cd ios
pod deintegrate
pod install
```