# "No Such Module FirebaseMessaging" after removing 'use_frameworks!' in Podfile

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods, podfile

I'm trying to remove `use_frameworks!` from Podfile. The reason is because one of pod latest version needs to remove `use_frameworks` (TapTalk SDK). 
There is error `No such module Firebase` when trying to build the app.

[image]

After removing it, there is an error `no such module FirebaseMessaging` and also missing remote config module in some file. 
If i undo it back to `use_frameworks!` -> it is back to normal.

What should I do to make it work?

Here is my Podfile, the problem happens in `Common` and also `xxxNotif(NotificationService)`

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

workspace 'xxx'

def main
  pod 'Kingfisher', :git => 'https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher.git', :branch => 'version6-xcode13'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'SkeletonView'
  pod 'JXPageControl'
  pod 'SwiftSoup'
end

target 'xxx' do
  project 'xxx.xcodeproj'
  
  main
  pod 'IOSSecuritySuite'
  pod 'TapTalkLive'
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 4.0.0', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'JSONModel', '~> 1.1', :modular_headers => true
  
end

target 'Networking' do
  project 'Networking/Networking.xcodeproj'
  
end

target 'Common' do
  project 'Common/Common.xcodeproj'
  
  main
end

target 'xxxNotif' do
  
  main
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with FirebaseCrashlytics. This is helped for me:

Podfile:

```
# use_frameworks! - not used
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '10.2.0', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics', '10.2.0', :modular_headers => true
pod 'GoogleUtilities', '7.10.0', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
```

In swift project file I use:

```
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAnalytics
import FirebaseCrashlytics
```

Answer (score 0):

As a work around you can try adding firebase as dependency rather than pod. Firebase has provided full documentation for that purpose [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods)

Swift Package Manager support requires 13.3.1 or higher.

If migrating from a CocoaPods-based project, run pod deintegrate to remove CocoaPods from your Xcode project. The CocoaPods-generated .xcworkspace file can safely be deleted afterward. If you're adding Firebase to a project for the first time, this step can be ignored.
In Xcode, install the Firebase libraries by navigating to File > Add Packages
In the prompt that appears, select the Firebase GitHub repository:

> https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git

Select the version of Firebase you want to use. For new projects, we recommend using the newest version of Firebase.
Choose the Firebase libraries you want to include in your app.

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to always open `.xcworkspace` instead of `.xcodeproj`

Comment: Is this a comment? If it's an answer, please elaborate to make it understandable. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer